# PowerPoint VBA code fails on second run without restarting ppt

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I'm using PowerPoint 2013 on a Surface to run a slideshow. During the slideshow, there is code that tracks the time as every slide changes and records that in a separate Excel file.

It works how I would like on the first time that I run through PowerPoint. However, if I don't close PowerPoint and restart the program, the second time through it will not do anything. The code works until the first instance of "ActiveSheet" or "ActiveCell". As soon as it gets to that line of code, the code just stops running. It doesn't stop the slideshow, but it doesn't record any data.

It seems like somehow PowerPoint loses the link to Excel.

What would cause it to fail on "ActiveSheet" or "ActiveCell"?

### Code for Timer

```
Dim intSlide As Integer
Dim oExcel As Excel.Application 
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim strPart As String
Dim strCond As String
Dim intRow As Integer

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" (lpsystemtime As SYSTEMTIME)
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Type SYSTEMTIME
    Year As Integer
    Month As Integer
    DayOfWeek As Integer
    Day As Integer
    Hour As Integer
    Minute As Integer
    Second As Integer
    Milliseconds As Integer
End Type
```

### Code that runs with every page change

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal ssw As SlideShowWindow)
    Dim sTime As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim check
    Dim strFinal As String

    GetSystemTime sTime

    intSlide = 1
    lngCount = 1
    intRow = 1
    strFinal = ""

    intSlide = ssw.View.CurrentShowPosition

    If intSlide = 1 Then
        Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
        Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ayse Eren\Desktop\TimeSaver.xlsx")
        oExcel.Visible = False
        oExcel.Sheets(1).Activate
        oExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Activate
        strCond = "HUD"
        If oExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "" Then
            oExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Participant"
            Range("A2").Activate
        Else
            oExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Activate
            'uses column B (automatically populated) to determine where to start recording data
        End If

        intRow = ActiveCell.Row - 1
    End If

    oExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (intSlide + intRow)).Activate

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = strCond
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = intSlide
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = sTime.Year
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = sTime.Month
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = sTime.Day
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = sTime.Hour
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = sTime.Minute
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = sTime.Second
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = sTime.Milliseconds

    strFinal = ActivePresentation.Slides(intSlide).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12) = strFinal

    If intSlide = 47 Then
        oWB.Save
        oExcel.Visible = True
        oExcel.Quit
    Else
        oWB.Save
    End If

End Sub
```

This code runs if you exit the slide show before slide 47.

### ***Edit***

```
Sub OnSlideShowTerminate(ByVal SSW As SlideShowWindow)
    oWb.Save
    oWb.Close
    oExcel.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: (1) Is the last slide actually slide 47?  If you add a slide, your code will never close the workbook.  (2) Where do you declare `ActiveCell`?  I see `oExcel.ActiveSheet` but I would have thought you would need `oExcel.ActiveCell` unless you assign a value to `ActiveCell` somewhere in the PPT code.  **Edit** welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for info and a badge :) .

Comment: @cxw 
(1) 47 is not my last slide, but I use 'OnSlideShowTerminate' in a separate sub to close everything out. 
(2) I thought that using 'oExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Activate' has now activated A1 in the spreadsheet, making that my active cell. After that, I thought using 'ActiveCell."... would call back to the cell that I selected.

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet, would you please edit the question to include the `OnSlideShowTerminate` code?

Comment: I've included the 'OnSlideShowTerminate' code. However, the slideshow should almost always run to completion. Therefore, this code doesn't typically run @cxw

Comment: I note that `PageChange` doesn't run `oWB.Close`, and `Terminate` doesn't run `oExcel.Quit`.  If you add `oWB.Close` to `PageChange` and `oExcel.Quit` to `Terminate`, does that make any difference?  Also, try adding `set oExcel=Nothing` both places you shut down Excel (shouldn't make a difference, but can't hurt).  Final thought: put `oExcel.` in front of all references to `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveCell`.  Maybe the Excel object library's top-level references are getting confused.